# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' in AWS EFS while loading an embeddings model

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-lambda

I trained a Tensorflow model that uses [BioSentVec embeddings](https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/BioSentVec) for preprocessing the model inputs. This embedding model is 20GB in size, so I could not deploy the final model in AWS Lambda (size limit of 512 MB) or in docker (size limit of 10 GB).

So, I decided to go with `Lambda + EFS` and I was successfully able to -

- Mount the Lambda on EFS
- Download all dependencies and libraries (NumPy, pandas, TensorFlow, etc..)
- Download the Biosentvec embeddings in EFS from S3 (by using an EC2 instance)

Now, when I try to load the embeddings model in the lambda using the following code -

```py
import json
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/mnt/access')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import sent2vec
from nltk import word_tokenize
import nltk

efs_path = "/mnt/access"
model_path = os.path.join(efs_path, 'models/BioSentVec_PubMed_MIMICIII-bigram_d700.bin')

model = sent2vec.Sent2vecModel()
try:
    model.load_model(model_path)
    print('BioSentVec model successfully loaded')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The lambda says -

> Process exited before completing the request

When I check the cloudwatch logs,  I see the following error -

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

I have also tried loading a simple text file inside of lambda from the same `models` directory on EFS and that works fine.

Can someone tell me what is happening and point me towards a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Lambda's are limited to 3GB of *memory* which has nothing to do with how much disk space is attached.  It looks like you're running out of memory.

Comment: So what. can I do here? Can I have a python script in EFS which can be invoked by lambda to load the model?

Comment: If you need 20GB of memory or more then you can't use a Lambda.  You'll need an EC2 instance to do this.